# Get count of unique ObjectId from array MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm new to working with MongoDb and do not know a lot of things.
I need to write an aggregation request.
Here is the JSON document structure.

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a72f7a75ef7d430e8c462d2"), 
    "crawler_id" : ObjectId("5a71cbb746e0fb0007adc6c2"), 
    "skill" : "stack", 
    "created_date" : ISODate("2018-02-01T13:19:03.522+0000"), 
    "modified_date" : ISODate("2018-02-01T13:22:23.078+0000"), 
    "connects" : [
        {
            "subskill" : "we’re", 
            "weight" : NumberInt(1), 
            "parser_id" : [
                ObjectId("5a71d88d5ef7d41964fbec11")
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "subskill" : "b1", 
            "weight" : NumberInt(2), 
            "parser_id" : [
                ObjectId("5a71d88d5ef7d41964fbec11"), 
                ObjectId("5a71d88d5ef7d41964fbec1b")
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "subskill" : "making", 
            "weight" : NumberInt(2), 
            "parser_id" : [
                ObjectId("5a71d88d5ef7d41964fbec1b"), 
                ObjectId("5a71d88d5ef7d41964fbec1c")
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "subskill" : "delivery", 
            "weight" : NumberInt(2), 
            "parser_id" : [
                ObjectId("5a71d88d5ef7d41964fbec1c"), 
                ObjectId("5a71d88d5ef7d41964fbec1e")
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I need the result return the name of skill and the number of unique parser_id.
In this case, the result should be:

```
[
   {
    "skill": "stack",
    "quantity": 4
    }
]
```

where "stack" - skill name,
and "quantity" - count of unique parser_id.

```
ObjectId("5a71d88d5ef7d41964fbec11")
ObjectId("5a71d88d5ef7d41964fbec1b")
ObjectId("5a71d88d5ef7d41964fbec1c")
ObjectId("5a71d88d5ef7d41964fbec1e")
```

Can some one help me with this request ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the document supplied in your question, this command ...

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$connects" },

    // count all occurrences
    { "$group": { "_id": {skill: "$skill", parser_id: "$connects.parser_id"}, "count": { "$sum": 1 } }},

    // sum all occurrences and count distinct
    { "$group": { "_id": "$_id.skill", "quantity": { "$sum": 1 } }},

    // (optional) rename the '_id' attribute to 'skill'
    { $project: { 'skill': '$_id', 'quantity': 1, _id: 0 } }
])
```

... will return:

```
{
    "quantity" : 4,
    "skill" : "stack"
}
```

The above command groups by `skill` and `connects.parser_id` and then gets a distinct count of those groups.

Your command includes the `java` tag so I suspect you are looking to execute the same command using the MongoDB Java driver. The code below (using MongoDB Java driver v3.x) will return the same result:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = ...;

MongoCollection<Document> collection = mongoClient.getDatabase("...").getCollection("...");

List<Document> documents = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
        Aggregates.unwind("$connects"),
        new Document("$group", new Document("_id", new Document("skill", "$skill").append("parser_id", "$connects.parser_id"))
                .append("count", new Document("$sum", 1))),
        new Document("$group", new Document("_id", "$_id.skill").append("quantity", new Document("$sum", 1))),
        new Document("$project", new Document("skill", "$_id").append("quantity", 1).append("_id", 0))
)).into(new ArrayList<>());

for (Document document : documents) {
    logger.info("{}", document.toJson());
}
```

Note: this code deliberately uses the form `new Document(<pipeline aggregator>, ...)` instead of the `Aggregators` utilities to make it easier to *see* the translation between the shell command and its Java equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but your command don't work correctly. I tried copy this command, open IntelliShell in Mongo3T, put there your code, and result for "stack" was correct, but for another documents in collection - result was wrong. I don't know  where is mistake.
P.S. Thanks for java code realization.

Comment: Can you please clarify what this means: "but for another documents in collection - result was wrong."? The more detail you provide, the better :)

Answer (score 0):

try `$project` with `$reduce`

`$setUnion` is used to keep only the distinct ids and finally `$size` used to get the distinct array count

```
db.col.aggregate(
    [
        {$project : {
                _id : 0,
                skill : 1,
                quantity : {$size :{$reduce : {input : "$connects.parser_id", initialValue : [] , in : {$setUnion : ["$$value", "$$this"]}}}}
            }
        }
    ]
).pretty()
```

result

```
{ "skill" : "stack", "quantity" : 4 }
```

Comment: Thanks, your command work correctly for all documents. Result return array of all documents in collection. 
But if i need to find some document by key word (in this case key word "stack"), and result returns me an array, only with this one document. How do this ?

Comment: do you want to filter some documents and find distinct?

Comment: Yes. I understood.
Need add command { $match : { skill : "key_word" } }

Comment: Yes,you need add `$match` stage then `$project`

Comment: May i ask something else?
I need add subskill name and subskill weight.
Here example:
[link](https://gist.github.com/LaYJeL/303aa24814682e25321aa5fec9613a6b)
Can you help ? :)

Comment: you just need to add subskill name and weight in the project, 1 enables in output 0 disables